# External CSS style sheet in Eclipse E4 RCP application

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

How can I specify a non `plugin:/...` URI as a style sheet location for the **org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme** plugin?

I tried using `file://...`, to no avail. Relative paths also do not work, as it is assumed they point within the plugin.

The reason behind this is to allow users of the plugin to customize the stylesheet, without having to unpack>modify>repack the JAR application bundle on their own.

Comment: You can specify that a plugin is not stored in a jar to make it easier to change things - the 'org.eclipse.ui.themes' plugin is like this.

Comment: @greg-449 How to specify that the plugin should not be packaged as a JAR? Also, is there no other way around such as the ability to specify a file outside the bundle? I fail to see the reason why not.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the theme engine if the URI does not start with `platform:/plugin/` it is added (with the current plugin id). This is to allow abbreviated URIs but means you can't use any other form.

You can specify that a plugin is not packaged in a jar in the product. If you are using 'features' for the product build specify `unpack="true"` in the `plugin` entry in the 'features.xml'

You can also specify

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

in the plugin's MANIFEST.MF (note this is overridden by the 'unpack' value in the feature.xml if you are using that).